# What the difference for the `STRSAFE_NO_TRUNCATION` and `STRSAFE_NULL_ON_FAILURE` values?

Tags: c++, string, winapi

The `StringCchCopyEx` function has values `STRSAFE_NULL_ON_FAILURE` and `STRSAFE_NO_TRUNCATION` for own flags. I am reading [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms647529%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and I don't see their difference:

> **STRSAFE_NULL_ON_FAILURE**
>
> If the function fails, *pszDest* is set to an empty string (`TEXT("")`).
>   In the case of a `STRSAFE_E_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER` failure, any truncated
>   string is overwritten.
>
> **STRSAFE_NO_TRUNCATION**
>
> As in the case of `STRSAFE_NULL_ON_FAILURE`, if the function fails,
>   *pszDest* is set to an empty string (`TEXT("")`). In the case of a
>   `STRSAFE_E_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER` failure, any truncated string is
>   overwritten.

Also I don't see the difference in my code results:

```
LPCTSTR pSrc = L"ASDFGHJK";

size_t charsCount = 5;
size_t buffer_size = charsCount * sizeof(TCHAR);
TCHAR *buffer = (TCHAR *) malloc(buffer_size);
ZeroMemory(buffer, buffer_size);    

// Now I generate the STRSAFE_E_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER result...

LPTSTR pDestEnd = NULL;
size_t remaind = 0;

// The MEMORY content after the StringCchCopyEx executing:
// 00 00 53 00 44 00 46 00 00 00 fd fd fd fd ab ab ab ab ab
// DWORD dwFlags = STRSAFE_FILL_BYTE('X') | STRSAFE_NO_TRUNCATION;

// The MEMORY content after the StringCchCopyEx executing:
// 00 00 53 00 44 00 46 00 00 00 fd fd fd fd ab ab ab ab ab
DWORD dwFlags = STRSAFE_FILL_BYTE('X') | STRSAFE_NULL_ON_FAILURE;

HRESULT result = StringCchCopyEx(buffer, charsCount, pSrc, &pDestEnd, &remaind, dwFlags);
```

For both cases the memory has the same content... What the difference for the `STRSAFE_NO_TRUNCATION` and `STRSAFE_NULL_ON_FAILURE` values?

Answer (score 1):

A safe string function with confuzzling documentation, what could go wrong?   The difference between the two is exactly where the zero-terminator is written when you also use STRSAFE_FILL_ON_FAILURE with a non-zero filler:

- Use STRSAFE_NO_TRUNCATION if you want to see the filler in the resulting string, the zero is written at the end.
- Use STRSAFE_NULL_ON_FAILURE to always get an empty string.  The filler is still written but past the 0.

Do beware of a flaw in the way the filler works.  The probably reason behind the confusing docs.  It can only be a value between 0 and 255, that of course can only really work properly for StringCchCopyExA().  The Unicode version will produce Chinese, "塘塘塘塘" in your case, pretty much forcing you to use 0 as the filler.  In which case there is indeed no difference anymore and the docs are accurate enough.